# Calulate space for photo capture in android

Tags: android, image-processing, storage, photos, image-capture

Hi can anyone help me how to find the maximum number of photos that can be captured with the available/remaining storage space in android programatically.

Comment: It won't be possible to give an exact number because the size of each photo can vary based on the contents e.g. a photo of plain sky will be smaller than a photo with lots of detail. It will also depend on the resolution as well. Check out this question for how to get a list of supported photo sizes on a device: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993652/android-camera-supported-picture-sizes You could measure the file size of a typical photo at different resolutions to estimate file size per megapixel. Then use that to work out the number of photos remaining for a given megapixel resolution.

Comment: Hi Samgak thanks for your reply...But consider that I found out the maximum possible image/photo size I can get from my android device (in size , resolution) so is it possible to get an exact number  if i know the maximum image size...?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952469/determining-camera-resolution-i-e-megapixels-programatically-in-android

Comment: Take a few photos with your camera and check the file sizes. There will be a range of file sizes even for photos the same resolution, so an exact number isn't possible.

Comment: ya you are absolutely correct but imagine that I am taking 100 photos and as a average of those if I get a image of maximum size and if I keep that as a base size will it be possible..?

Comment: yes, that should work

Comment: ok thanks samgak I will try this...I thought there will a way like how we have for video.. thanks a lot man..:)